# Por que esta concatenando ao invés de somar?

Tags: javascript

O meu código está concatenando ao invés de somar. Qual é o erro?

```
var cFinal = 0;
var cFabrica = prompt("Insira o valor de fabrica do veículo");
var comissao = 0.28 * cFabrica;
var imposto = 0.45 * cFabrica;
cFinal = cFabrica + comissao + imposto;
document.write("O valor final é: ", cFinal);
```

Comment: Como sugestão, estude tipagem e operações em javascript. Como a linguagem não é fortemente tipada, erros como esse são comuns.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O problema é que o `prompt()` retorna uma *string*.

Isso não se percebe na multiplicação pois o JavaScript tenta converter em numeros mas quando começas essa concatenação com uma string, a conversão é da esquerda para a direita e fica tudo *string*.

Testa `typeof cFabrica` e vais ver que dá `string`.

A solução é converter em número para não haver dúvidas/bugs.

```js
var cFabrica = prompt("Insira o valor de fabrica do veículo");

// teste 1
console.log('cFabrica é do tipo:', typeof cFabrica);
var numerocFabrica = Number(cFabrica);

// teste 2
console.log('numerocFabrica é do tipo:', typeof numerocFabrica);

var comissao = 0.28 * cFabrica;
var imposto = 0.45 * cFabrica;
var cFinal = numerocFabrica + comissao + imposto;
console.log("O valor final é: ", cFinal);
```

Comment: Consegui resolver era apenas colocar um parseInt antes do prompt.

Comment: @NegoWell o `parseInt` é uma solução. Mas atenção se tiveres numero com parte decimal porque o `parseInt` só te dá inteiros.

Comment: @NegoWell Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é assinalando "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo. Adicionar uma nova resposta assim (que não é uma resposta pra pergunta e deve ser removida) deixa o site mais confuso e pode atrapalhar.

Answer (score 5):

```js
var cFinal = 0;
var cFabrica = prompt("Insira o valor de fabrica do veículo");
var comissao = 0.28 * cFabrica;
var imposto = 0.45 * cFabrica;
cFinal = parseFloat(cFabrica) + comissao + imposto;
document.write("O valor final é: ", cFinal);
```

O `prompt` retorna uma string, para fazer a soma, precisa de um `int`, entao usando `parseFlaot`, consegue somar.

Answer (score 5):

O que ocorre é que a função `prompt` sempre retorna uma string, então para que a conta final seja uma soma e não concatenação é necessário converter o retorno da função `prompt` para `float`:

```js
var cFinal = 0;
var cFabrica = parseFloat(prompt("Insira o valor de fabrica do veículo"));
var comissao = 0.28 * cFabrica;
var imposto = 0.45 * cFabrica;
cFinal = cFabrica + comissao + imposto;
document.write("O valor final é: ", cFinal);
```