# Calculo via Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo problemas para realizar um cálculo do preço de vários produtos no Front-end.

Eu tenho um `array` de produtos e eu preciso somar eles através de uma função.

Exemplo:

```
produto[0] = {produto:'Camisa',preco:'45,90'};
produto[0] = {produto:'Calça', preco:'100,99'};

function somarTudo(arrProdutos){
   var total = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < arrProdutos.length; i++) { 
          total += arrProdutos[i].preco;
      }
}

somarTudo(produto);
```

Só que está me dando um valor estranho como retorno:

```
"45,90100,99"
```

O que eu preciso fazer?

Comment: Você está tentando somar *strings*.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Por que esta concatenando ao invés de somar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233565/por-que-esta-concatenando-ao-inv%c3%a9s-de-somar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esses valores estão no formato *String* e não *Number*. E como o JavaScript usa o `+` também para juntar/concatenar strings ele acaba pensando que isso é texto.

Para transformares texto de numeros em numeros que o JavaScript pode ler tens de usar`.` para separar a parte decimal e não ter `,`. Então tens de tratar esse texto antes de usar/converter em numero.

Podes fazer assim:

```js
var produto = [{
    produto: 'Camisa',
    preco: '45,90'
  },
  {
    produto: 'Calça',
    preco: '100,99'
  }
];


function somarTudo(arrProdutos) {
  var total = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arrProdutos.length; i++) {
  var preco = arrProdutos[i].preco.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.');
    total += Number(preco);
  }
  return total;
}

var total = somarTudo(produto);
console.log(total); // 146.89
```

Outra sugestão poderia ser assim:

```js
var produto = [{
    produto: 'Camisa',
    preco: '45,90'
  },
  {
    produto: 'Calça',
    preco: '100,99'
  }
];


function somarTudo(arrProdutos) {
  return arrProdutos.reduce((soma, prod) => {
    var preco = prod.preco.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.');
    return soma += Number(preco);
  }, 0);
}

var total = somarTudo(produto);
console.log(total); // 146.89
```

Comment: Show, resolveu o problema. Valeu :D